# When > apply a performance and memory profiler?

Tags: performance

Based on your experience, when do you need to perform a performance and memory profiler for a web development project in C#?

Today, Im newbie in performance and memory profiling.

Comment: **[Unclear what help you need](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important).** Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell what problem you are trying to solve or what aspect of your approach needs to be corrected or explained. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a memory and performance profiler when you need to find out why your program is running too slow or using too much memory.  It will tell you which specific parts of your code are causing the problem, so that you can focus your efforts specifically on that code.

**Further Reading**
[Beginners Guide to Performance Profiling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your help. If I'm interpret correct from your side, you execute the performance and memory profiling in development phase?

Comment: Yes, the moment you suspect a *significant* performance problem.

Comment: 1. I have read that you need to make a isolation of the phase in order to make a performance testing? The purpose is that retrieve correct data  so much as possible without affected by network or other application etc.  Is it true or am I wrong?

Comment: 2. Do you know any good performance and memory profiling that is open source?

Comment: 3. Do you know if it common to use a test phase before production phase in order to commit performance testing?